# Azure Synapse Analytics Pipeline - Which IP range?

Tags: azure-synapse

I'm trying to set up an ELT pipeline to pull source data from a mySQL database into Synapse using the "Copy Data tool". The source mySQL database is operated by a 3rd party that requires me to provide an address (range) for their IP-whitelist.

I've searched around but cannot find the IP address range for "Azure Synapse Analytics"  -- but must admit that I'm new to Azure Synapse Analytics and very confused by the nomenclature.  E.g., I found this [Azure IP Range list](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519), which contains ranges for various services but none named "Synapse Analytics".

Where do I find the proper IP range? Or do I need to set up my Synapse Analytics with a fixed IP address, and if so, where do I find more information on that?

Comment: Is it feasible for you to install a self-hosted integration runtime either on-prem or in an Azure VM? Then set the mySQL linked service to use that IR. That’s the most straightforward way to get a consistent IP address for this pipeline.

Comment: Would a [managed private endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/synapse-workspace-managed-private-endpoints) help you?

Comment: We solved this using @GregGalloway's suggestion: self-hosted integration runtime either on-prem or in an Azure VM.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the current list of IP addresses for Azure SQL/Synapse Analytics here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-architecture#gateway-ip-addresses

Similarly, Synapse pipelines share many attributes with Data Factory pipelines, and the IP addresses should match. You can find those in the document you linked.

Keep in mind that this list doesn't change often, but it can change. Generally there will be an announcement ahead of time so you can update your firewalls.

Comment: I believe he’s talking about the pipelines part of Synapse not a SQL pool. So I don’t think this answer helps the OP

Comment: Sure thing @GregGalloway. I've edited my answer to include the information that Synapse Analytics Pipelines feature is built on top of Data Factory and should share those IP addresses.